# File array validation in Laravel 10

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-10

I'm trying to validate an input array of file types, and Laravel simply ignores it. See the html and validate in the controller. What am I doing wrong, and I don't see it? The other field's validation works perfectly.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, application/pdf" name="comprovante[]" id="comprovante-1"/>
```

```
$request->validate([
    'curso.*' => 'required|string|max:250',
    'tipo.*' => 'required|string|max:250',
    'instituicao.*' => 'required|string|max:250',
    'cidade.*' => 'required|string|max:250',
    'estado.*' => 'required|string|max:250',
    'anoinicio.*' => 'required|string|max:4',
    'anofinal.*' => 'required|string|max:4',
    'comprovante.*' => 'required|file',
]);
```

Comment: Ensure your form tag has the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute. This is required for forms that include file uploads.

Comment: Yes, I just checked. Even if you have a file, it will be uploaded normally. Only validation is ignored.

Comment: Rather than set `required` on array elements you should do so on the array itself, with any count requirements as well. `'comprovante' => ['array', 'min:1'], 'comprovante.*' => ['image'],`. Also do not rely on client-side to impose restrictions on file types.

Comment: Same thing, it simply ignores validation. I've already checked the field names several times, I've checked the form too. and when I use dd($request) everything is fine too. I'll try updating to laravel 11 and see what happens.

Comment: I agree with @miken32, especially adding file restrictions in the validation as well, using `mimes` and `mimetypes`. But, more importantly, I'm interested in knowing whether you verified that the execution continued past the validation. I've had situations where the script would validate but the errors did not flash to the `$errors` variable in Blade. Did you check if this is the case? Maybe add a `dd('Hi')` *after* the validation to see if it dumps it or it redirects you back. If it redirects you back, then it has more to do with the middleware.